# Open XML: как получить координаты объекта?

Tags: c#, парсер, openxml, powerpoint

До этого приходилось работать с `Open XML`, а именно с его обверткой ClosedXML, для Excel. А сейчас, уже работая с файлами `PowerPoint`, мне необходимо получить координаты объекта на слайде. И для начала, даже до самого объекта `Shape` не удается дойти/получить и максимум на что меня хватило так это

```
PresentationPart presentationPart;
using (PresentationDocument doc = PresentationDocument.Open(@"d:\test.pptx", false))
{                
    presentationPart = doc.PresentationPart;                

    var element = presentationPart.SlideParts.First().Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.First();

}
```

и я думал сейчас нажму "точку" `element.` и смогу получить все что мне необходимо), но не тут то было: там и намека нет на координаты.
Где все спрятано, **как мне получить координаты объекта `x` и `y` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добраться до координат в OpenXML оказалось не так-то легко, но возможно:

```
using (PresentationDocument doc = PresentationDocument.Open(@"d:\test.pptx", false))
{
    Slide firstSlide = doc.PresentationPart.SlideParts.First().Slide;
    CommonSlideData csd = firstSlide.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideData>();
    var shapes = csd.Descendants<Shape>();

    foreach (var shape in shapes)
    {                                                          
        var t2d = shape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D;
        if (t2d != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"X: {t2d.Offset.X}\nY: {t2d.Offset.Y}");
        }
    }
}
```